# Local notification repeatInterval

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

My app is about showing student timetable and I want to add a local notification `repeatInterval`.
I plan to use switch button for this.

I tried this code and it doesn't work right now :

```
    -(IBAction)theSwitch:(id)sender{
if (switcher.on) {
    NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateComponent setWeekday:3]; // For tuesday
    [dateComponent setHour:13];
    [dateComponent setMinute:41];

    NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"ALARM!"];
    [notification setFireDate:fireDate];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
else  {UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:nil];
}
    }
```

So I need some more guidance here on this and some suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: what's the issue you are facing? notification are not coming or repletion issue?

Comment: The issue is when I tern switch on my app break down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not able to get local notification than please check this code below.

Add code in AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *localNotification =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotification) {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@", localNotification);
}
return YES;
}
```

Add method to handle local notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
// Handle the notificaton when the app is running
NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@", notification);
}
```

Comment: My problem is when I tern the switch on then my app break down and say         `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`                                  . What should I do ?

Comment: It looks like when you are trying to add local notification app will crash, Can you please post your `AppDelegate.m` file's `didFinishLaunching` method code.

Comment: appDelegate.m `   // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotification =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification) {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@", localNotification);
    }
    return YES;
}`      note : I added my first code in view controller.m

Comment: could you help me please ??

Comment: @Faisal: I need to see your `AppDelegate.m` and `ViewController.m` files or relevant code. Is is possible for you to share your code?

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Handle launching from a notification
  UILocalNotification *localNotification =
  [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
   if (localNotification) {
      NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@", localNotification);
 }
    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  // Handle the notificaton when the app is running
  NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@", notification);}`

Comment: that was my appDelegate.m and what will come next is ViewController.m                                                  note : this is my first app so I'm sorry if I don't undrestand you

Comment: `-(IBAction)theSwitch:(id)sender{
    if (switcher.on) {
        NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        
        [dateComponent setWeekday:3]; // For tuesday
        [dateComponent setHour:13];
        [dateComponent setMinute:41];
        
        NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];`

Comment: `UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        [notification setAlertBody:@"ALARM!"];
        [notification setFireDate:fireDate];
        notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
    else  {UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:nil];
    }
}`

Comment: if you need my app AppDelegate.m and ViewController.m files give me your email to send it to you

Comment: @Faisal: Sorry for late response, I have use your code. The code for switch state on is working but your else part gives an exception. You can not set `nil` value to `scheduleLocalNotification`. To cancel notification change your else part with this code.

`else  {
        UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        
        // Or create an Object of local object to cancel specific notification objec.
        // [app cancelLocalNotification:notificationObject];
    }`

Comment: yeah that's work thanks a lot I appreciate your help and time. I have some more question but that will be awful if I ask you so I have to figure it out . thanks thanks thanks :)